# \g@addto@macro appending code using parameter

Tags: macros, expansion

After a lot of trial and error, I haven't been able to solve the following problem:
A simplified version: I want to use \g@addto@macro to add code to another macro wich will use a command of the macro, I expected this code to work:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1, }
\newcommand{\bar}[1]{
    \g@addto@macro\foo{
        ##1#1
    }
}
```

And to produce this output:

```
\foo{A} -> A,
\bar{B}
\show\foo = #1, #1B
\foo{A} -> A, AB
\bar{C}
\show\foo = #1, #1B#1C
\foo{A} -> A, ABAC
```

I hope it is clear what I want. In an actual implementation, I want to expand a \switch-like structure dynamically. The problem with the code is, that the `##` is not expanded to `#` when adding code, however `#1` is expanded to the first parameter of `\bar`. This causes

```
\bar{B}
\show\foo = #1, ##1B
```

wich in turn doesn't produce the desired output. I would like to avoid additional packages if possible.

Comment: Egreg's provided a solution but I'll note that apart from the problem with `#` you are missing several `%` which would add spurious space tokens to your result. `\g@addto@macro` goes to some lengths passing the tokens through a toks register specifically to prevent the need to double `#` (so you can build up strings including that character)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my original code I had the comments in; thanks for the advice though :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\g@addto@macro` uses a token register to *stop* the interpretation of `#` that you want.

You just want `\def`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1, }

\def\zfoo#1\relax{\long\def\foo##1{#1}}
\newcommand{\baR}[1]{%
   \expandafter\zfoo\foo{##1}##1#1\relax
}

\foo{A}
\show\foo


\baR{B}
\show\foo %= #1, #1B

\foo{A} %-> A, AB

\baR{C}
\show\foo% = #1, #1B#1C

\foo{A} %-> A, ABAC


\end{document}
```

which produces

```
> \foo=\long macro:
#1->#1, .
l.13 \show\foo

? 
> \foo=\long macro:
#1->#1, #1B.
l.17 \show\foo
               %= #1, #1B
? 
> \foo=\long macro:
#1->#1, #1B#1C.
l.22 \show\foo
              % = #1, #1B#1C
?
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't append tokens to a macro with parameters using `\g@addto@macro`. Nor you can do it with `\apptocmd` of `etoolbox`.

You can do it with `regexpatch`, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1,\space}
\newcommand{\baz}[1]{%
  \def\temp{#1}%
  \regexpatchcmd{\foo}{ \Z }{ \cP\#1 \u{temp} }{}{}%
}


\begin{document}

\foo{A}

\baz{B}\foo{A}

\baz{C}\foo{A}

\end{document}
```

The "search" regular expression matches the end of the replacement text; this is replaced by `\cP\#1` (which means `#1` with the correct category codes) followed by the expansion of the macro `\temp`. Thus I set `\temp` to the argument of `\baz`.

Unfortunately, the current version of `regexpatch` can't patch macros whose replacement text ends with a space, so in this particular case I used `\space` at the beginning.

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there's no way to, say manually set the catcode at the specific position? Or to adapt the code of `\g@addto@macro`? Seems like a serious flaw to me...

Comment: @AlexR Serious flaw (of LaTeX2e itself probably, but certainly of many packages) is the need for patching.

Comment: @AlexR it was written that way so you could use `\newcommand` in `\AtBeginDocument` in a way that you didn't have to have multiple doubling of `#`.